# Como usar taggleClass para 3 css diferentes?

Tags: jquery, html5

Ao acessar a pag, os titulos são cor=blue

Qdo clica no titulo a cor troca para cor=red (e abre conteúdo)

Mas qdo fecha o titulo volta para cor=blue

**Eu preciso:** Qdo clicar no titulo mude para a cor=red e qdo clicar novamente ao sair fique cor=green

Agradeço a ajuda.

```
JQ321
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abre').on('click' , function(){ // abre tudo
        $('.titulo .conteudo').show();
        });
    $('#fecha').on('click' , function(){ // fecha tudo
        $('.titulo .conteudo').hide();
    });
    $('.titulo').on('click' , function(){ // abre/fecha cada titulo
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#tit'+id).toggle();
        var classes = ['red','green']; // Nomes das classes CSS
        this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length]; // Altera a class conforme o clique
    });
});

CSS
.titulo {color:blue}
.red {color:red}
.green {color:green}
.conteudo {display: none;}

@media(min-width:800px){
.lista-titulos {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    }
.titulo,.mostra{
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
@media(min-width:1024px){
.titulo {cursor:pointer}
.titulo:hover {background:yellow}

PHP/HTML5
<div class="lista-titulos">
   BD select while...
  <div class="titulo" id="<?=$id?>"><span class="tit<?=$id?>"><?=$perg?>/span>
    <span id="tit<?=$id?>" class="conteudo">
        <div class="mostra">TEXTO</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

NO RODAPÉ
<div><button type="button" id="abre">abrir tudo</button> <button type="button" id="fecha">fechar tudo</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que você deseja.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#abre').on('click' , function(){ // abre tudo
    $('.titulo .conteudo').show();
  });
  $('#fecha').on('click' , function(){ // fecha tudo
    $('.titulo .conteudo').hide();
  });
  $('.titulo').on('click' , function(){ // abre/fecha cada titulo
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#tit'+id).toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass(function() {
      // Altera a classe CSS
      return $(this).is('.red, .green') ? 'red green' : 'red';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.titulo {color:blue}
.red {color:red}
.green {color:green}
.conteudo {display: none;}

@media(min-width:800px){
.lista-titulos {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    }
.titulo,.mostra{
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
@media(min-width:1024px){
.titulo {cursor:pointer}
.titulo:hover {background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titulo" id="01">
  <span class="cor01">TITULO 01</span>
    <span id="tit01" class="conteudo">Conteudo 01</span>
</div>
<div class="titulo" id="02">
  <span class="cor02">TITULO 02</span>
    <span id="tit02" class="conteudo">Conteudo 02</span>
</div>
<div class="titulo" id="03">
  <span class="cor03">TITULO 03</span>
    <span id="tit03" class="conteudo">Conteudo 03</span>
</div>
<div class="titulo" id="04">
  <span class="cor04">TITULO 04</span>
    <span id="tit04" class="conteudo">Conteudo 04</span>
</div>
<div><button type="button" id="abre">abrir tudo</button> <button type="button" id="fecha">fechar tudo</button></div>
```

Comment: Wéllingthon, obrigado pela rápida resposta, a sua função está perfeita, mas está conflitando com a função abre/fecha todos os títulos. (Qdo abre individual e depois clica em abrir tudo, fica confuso) Fiz um update da função completa, o css e o html. Desculpe-me por não ter informado corretamente. Agradeço sua atenção e tempo dispensado Abs.

Comment: @Geo veja agora, o que estava acontecendo é que ao clicar no titulo alterava o valor do atributo *Class* de `class="titulo"` para  `class="red"` dai o *jQuery* não achava o seletor `.titulo`.

Comment: está perfeito. NOTA 1000 pela sua atenção e paciência. Analisei o código e aprendi mais um pouco. Um abraço e muito obrigado.

Comment: Sou novo aqui e ví que a minha pergunta está -1. Será que foi muito básica, mal formulada ou fora do contexto? Quem pontua é o Administrador? É só curiosidade rsrs. Abs e obrigado de novo, ficou ótimo!!!!

Comment: Veja [Central de ajuda > Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), você pode melhorar ela, formatando, e explicando seu problema, etc. Veja esse link que passei.